# aws console unable to login with root credentials Page not getting loaded

Tags: amazon-web-services

I cant login with root credentials in aws console.  I was accessing different aws account.  Cleared the cookies  .  When I click on the link "sign with root account"   the page doesnt get loaded. I cant raise it with aws support as I cant login using root account.  Not sure what i can do

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? A different computer? Do you have a non-root account you could try?

Comment: Thanks . Apologies for the delayed response.  Tried in mobile and created a new user id.   Account Id gets attached to the browser and not able to clear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark B's approach is your best bet. Whenever I have to log in as root I use a different browser.

Comment: Thanks . Apologies for the delayed response. Tried in mobile and created a new user id. Account Id gets attached to the browser and not able to clear it